# Infer type depending on other field type

Tags: typescript

I am implementing a custom table component where developer can customize the way certain cell data is rendered. To make it more foolproof, I am trying to make TS infer the type of `render()` argument based on the `User` property chosen in `id` property to the type of that property.

```js
interface Col<T extends Record<string, any>> {
  id: (keyof T & string);
  render: (data: T[this["id"]]) => string;
}

interface User {
  name: string;
  enabled: boolean;
}

const cols: Array<Col<User>> = [
  {
    id: "name",
    render: (name: string) => name;
  },
  {
    id: "enabled",
    render: (enabled: boolean) => enabled ? "yes" : "no";
  }
];
```

but following error is produced:

```
      TS2322: Type '(name: string) => string' is not assignable to type '(data: string | boolean) => string'.
  Types of parameters 'name' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This is because the first argument of `render()` is inferred as union `string | boolean` (and more types if `User` interface contains more). I was expecting `T[this["id"]]` to return the type of actual property chosen in `this.id` property but it seems to expand to an union of all possible choices instead.

Is there any way to make the type resolution dynamic without adding another generic parameter to `Col`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to create a union of all allowed states:

```js
interface User {
    name: string;
    enabled: boolean;
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Union<T> = Values<{
    [Prop in keyof T]: {
        id: Prop,
        render: (name: T[Prop]) => string
    }
}>

type Result = Union<User>[]

const cols: Result = [
    {
        id: "name",
        render: (name /** string */) => name
    },
    {
        id: "enabled",
        render: (enabled /** boolean */) => enabled ? "yes" : "no"
    }
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDc%20hExARgDYQAmlbA9vy5wQTAL65cYAJ4AHFADU4HAK4R0AHgAqAPmQBeZFoDaAawjT%20MIwF1JM%20WhDB%20IbXsNLV6jXkLJjAAUofllkUGRzS2stG0o-f0JgXmRg0IAaZkTkKFZuaEoACmIyShM02RsASgM9aloQOizkCTEdezkUACV1FQ4wAycXNwxoHWM7XARXamRpjnRKHvQ%20gcNjZoTs5MoAIhKIXczsglyQfKgig5r9PQPmsWPCLcSd5F3WOE4eI%20b-M4uRU%20324Nz0wK43GQAH53tJ1LtkHsQPxdg9cDYGEA)

`Union` - iterates through each `User` property and creates an object:

```js
{
 id: Prop,
 render: (value: User[Prop])=>string
}
```

This object is important for us. In order to obtain it, we should use `Values` helper. It returns a union of all object values.

Comment: Thanks! You have incredible knowledge about TS!
Is there a way to handle the situation when someone passes `Record<string, any>` as `T`? In this case during iteration over T keys only the first column is "remembered" and triggering an error.

Comment: @IonBazan what result do you expect if someone provide Record<string,any>?

Comment: @IonBazan do you want to forbid passing `Record<string, any>` ?

Comment: I was expecting it would infer `data` argument to be `any` in that case and `id` property to accept any string in this case. 

Thanks again for your help here. It means a lot!

Comment: @IonBazan it behaves exactly how you describe. Try to create an array with `Record<string, any>`

Comment: You are right - I was checking that in my actual code and TS was resolving that `Record` as just `{ name: any }`. It seems to be caused by default template value in my table component: `class Table<T = Record<string, any>>`. If I don't specify `T` when initialising the table: `<Table columns={...} />` it fails to properly resolve. Explicitly initializing it with: `<Table<Record<string, any>> columns={...} />` works well though. I wonder why is that so, but it's not a big issue anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238903/discussion-between-ion-bazan-and-captain-yossarian).